# Line chart is drawing before first point in Chart.js

Tags: chart.js, linechart

I'm trying to draw a line plus bar chart.
Whenever i try to draw the line chart (I tried drawing only the line chart, same error), a line is drawn before the first point:

[Line Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3wYt.png)

This is the first time i tried Chart.js 2.0, the other charts i drew look great, except this one... Any ideas?

Code:

```
function Data() {
    $scope.barChartData = {
        labels: $scope.mesesLabels,
        datasets: [
            {
                type: 'bar',
                label: "" + myDate.getFullYear() - 1,
                backgroundColor: "#5799c7",
                data: $scope.infoAnoAnterior,
                borderColor: 'white',
                borderWidth: 2,
            },
            {
                type: 'bar',
                label: "" + myDate.getFullYear(),
                backgroundColor: "#ff7c40",
                data: $scope.infoAnoAtual,
            },
            {
                type: 'line',
                label: 'Média entre anos',
                backgroundColor: "rgba(220,20,20,0)",
                data: $scope.mediaEntreAnos,
                borderColor: 'red',
                borderWidth: 2,
                pointBorderColor: 'black',
                pointBackgroundColor: 'black'
            }, ]
    };
    drawChart();
}

function drawChart(){ 
    var ctx = document.getElementById("base").getContext("2d");
    window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: $scope.barChartData,
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Chart.js Combo Bar Line Chart'
            },
            legend: {
                display: true,
                labels: {
                    fontColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)'
                }
            },                
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Add option scaleBeginAtZero: true,

Comment: @NagaSaiA
Didn't work, same thing happens...

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible you have a problem with input values, not with chart options? I.e. some duplicate values.

Comment: Just double checked, don't have any duplicates either

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, add below to options

```
scaleStartValue: 0
```

Comment: that also did not work... Got any other suggestions? If i have a null value on the first position of my Data array the line doesn't appear, but the chart is incorrect... Thanks for your time by the way!

Answer (score 0):

I added the latest versions of chart.js (2.2.1) on my project and it worked, dunno why 2.0 didn't, but thanks for your time!